# Why does the Stack snippets console error not show the correct line number?

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

When there is an error in a Stack snippet JavaScript code, an error message is displayed, but the "lineno" in the message is incorrect.

In the following snippet, it Shows the error is on line 30, but the Last line of the snippet is line 24.

Here is the snippet in question:

```js
let users = {};

function user(name,real){
  this.username = name,
  this.realname = real,
  this.id = Math.floor(Math.random() *1000);
  this.subs = 0,
  this.videos = [],
  this.listuser = function() {
    return this.username;
  }
};
function newuser(name, email,username){
  users[name] = new user(username, name);
};


let savefile = () => {
        
  var channame = string(document.getElementById('channame'));
  var name = string(document.getElementById('name'));
  var email = string(document.getElementById('email'));
  newuser(name,email,channame);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>youtube ripoff</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <br> <br><br><br><br><br>
  <form action="">
  <label for="username">Channel Name: </label>
  <input type="text" id="channame" name="channelname"><br>
  Real Name
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
  Email
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onmousedown="newuser('name1','name@gmail.com','channelname1');">
  <br><br><br><br>
  
  <input type="button" value="Load Channels" id="seech" name="seechannels" onmousedown="alert(users['name1'].listuser());"><br>
  </form>
    <script src="script.js">
    function fun(){
      window.alert("starting program...")
      //other code
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The error can be reproduced by clicking the 'Load Channels' button.

Why does this happen?

Comment: I don't know much about the Stack snippet, but perhaps you'd want to add that same snippet in your Question here.

Comment: Possibly related: [Why this snippet is giving me incorrect line numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66388806/why-this-snippet-is-giving-me-incorrect-line-numbers/)

Comment: @N_R01 In your Question here. This Question.. so people can verify it. Right now.. it's an image of code. I'm almost certain that no one wants to transcribe this just to check it.

Comment: Even in the image, I don't understand why you're not actually showing the line (that presumably _isn't_ 30) where the error occurs.

Comment: Agreed with @jonrsharpe above - it looks like there could be line 30. Also fully agreed with Scratte - if you add the exact snippet here (in your question) instead, we will have a way to reproduce it. With an image, it's anyone's guess

Comment: See in https://i.stack.imgur.com/vk5SV.png this doesn't have a line 30 in JS field

Comment: MCVE, please! :) There are at least 2 users that asked you for one at this point.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand what r u asking

Comment: Yea It's true  , its from that question

Comment: I was answering that question

Comment: Oh, I was just asking why that error shows that was in lineno 30

Comment: Now see, No need of taking that question here

Comment: Well... It's actually pretty easy to determine why :) If you inspect the network tab in your devtools, there is a request to stacksnippets.net/js which returns a fully parsed HTML document with all your JS, CSS, and HTML combined. Line 30 there is `<input type="button" value="Load Channels" id="seech" name="seechannels" onmousedown="alert(users['name1'].listuser());">` which is one causing the error

Comment: :( I didn't get that

Comment: so, to continue what I mentioned above, *technically*, the snippet reports the issue correctly. However, the report is also pretty useless, that is true (unless you inspect the network response, of course). You see, the problem is that Stack snippets is an under-developed feature that the company is not very keen on improving

Comment: If I (or someone else) will not be able to find a feature request to close against, it will make sense to convert your question into a feature request for improving snippets (to preserve the original line mapping - although it does not seem trivial at all). That said, please note that it might take forever for the company to address that

Comment: On an off-note - please do not obfuscate code snippets and override improvements to the post made by users with edit privilege, thank you.

Comment: Oh, Now I got that :), Thanks @OlegValter

Comment: @N_R01 No worries :) If you want to, change your question to [meta-tag:feature-request], it will not hurt - but I doubt the company gets to it in any foreseeable future